# Evaluate $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{a_n}{b_n}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, recurrence-relations

Let $a_n$ and $b_n$ be a recursive sequence with seed value $a_0=0,a_1=1$, $b_0=1$ and $b_1=2$ such that

$$\begin{align} \\ &a_{n+1}=(4n+2)a_n+a_{n-1}\\\\&b_{n+1}=(4n+2)b_n + b_{n-1} \end{align}$$

Find $\displaystyle\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{a_n}{b_n}$. (Ans. $\frac{e-1}{e+1}$)

I don't know how to start. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can try to solve the recurrence for each sequence (ie, find a formula), then plug into the limit. Do you know how to solve this kind of recurrence?

Comment: I don't know, sir.

Comment: I calculate $0.45543809977901$ as the ratio. Not sure how to solve the recurrence relation ... someone give me a clue ? We could use generating functions ?

Comment: the answer is $\frac{e-1}{e+1}$ but i don't know how to solve.

Comment: 0.46211716 by calculation ... in agreement with the value you state ... this is very similar to Euler's continued fraction for e.

Comment: It's the answer, but I don't know how I get it.

Comment: another way to solve this is via generating functions...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint**: the continued fraction of $\tanh\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)$ is given by:
$$ \tanh\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)=[0;2,6,10,14,18,22, 26, 30, 34, 38, 42,\ldots]\tag{1}$$
due to [Gauss' continued fraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss's_continued_fraction), and your sequence $\left\{\frac{a_n}{b_n}\right\}_{n\geq 1}$ is just the sequence of convergents of the RHS of $(1)$.

---

If you change the initial values $a_0,a_1,b_0,b_1$, the limit takes the form $\frac{a+bz}{c+dz}$ with $z=\tanh\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)$ by the general theory of continued fractions.

Comment: I'm very confused how I get $\tanh \frac{1}{2}$ that is the limit.

Comment: @MoNtiDeaDMoonDogs: I just recognized by experience a well-known continued fraction.

Comment: @MoNtiDeaDMoonDogs: see also here: https://topologicalmusings.wordpress.com/2008/08/04/continued-fraction-for-e/

Comment: If I change the seed value, what should i get the limit. i mean that different seed value, it may imply different value of limit.

Comment: @MoNtiDeaDMoonDogs: if you change the initial values, you get something of the form $\frac{a+bz}{c+dz}$ where $z=\tanh\frac{1}{2}$. This follows from the general theory of continued fractions.

Comment: I see but I'm still confused that I get the limit is $z=\tanh\frac{1}{2}$, but It's not $\frac{a+bz}{c+dz}$. 

I appreciate all your help and It's better if you show the value is $\tanh\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: @MoNtiDeaDMoonDogs: you asked me a different thing, you asked me *what happens if we change the initial values?*. If we leave the initial values as they are, the sequence of $\frac{a_n}{b_n}$ is the sequence of convergents of a continued fraction, the RHS of $(1)$. But such continued fraction is well-known, hence the limit is given by the whole continued fraction, i.e. $\tanh\frac{1}{2}$. Is is clear now?

Comment: I'm sorry, sir. I know it's convergent and equal to $\tanh\frac{1}{2}$ that is continued fraction. if I change the initial values of $a_n$ or $b_n$, the limit will change to $\frac{a+bz}{c+dz}$, $z=\tanh\frac{1}{2}$. I would like to know that $a_0=0,a_1=1,b_0=1$ and $b_1=2$, I will get the value is $\tanh\frac{1}{2}$, but not $\frac{a+bz}{c+dz}$.

Comment: Is it the general initial value of sequence for limit or continued fraction?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53519/discussion-between-montidead-moondogs-and-jack-daurizio).

Comment: @MoNtiDeaDMoonDogs: as already said, if you leave the initial values as they are defined in your question, you exactly get the sequence of convergents of the RHS of $(1)$.

Comment: Thank you, sir. I see the Generalized Continued Fraction.

Comment: I'm sorry for my confusion.